# Convert Map to ImmutableSetMultimap

Tags: java, dictionary, guava, immutability

I am trying to convert the following piece of code to use `ImmutableSetMultimap`, but I run into problems when I try to do `map.get(...).add(...)` because its immutable.  Is there an easy way to do this?

```
List<MyObject> objects   

Map<Long, Set<Key>> map = new HashMap<Long, Set<Key>>();
for (MyObject entry : objects) {
    if (map.containsKey(entry.getId())) {
        map.get(entry.getId()).add(entry.getKey());
    } else {
        Set<Key> newSet = new HashSet<Key>();
        newSet.add(entry.getKey());
        map.put(entry.getId(), newSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Object` doesn't have `getKey()` method

Comment: How does this even compile? `Object` doesn't have a `getKey` or `getId` method.

Comment: Share `MyCustomObject` as well

Comment: As far as I can tell, your Sets aren't immutable, since they're HashSets. What's the problem here?

Comment: Its just a basic object with key and id fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImmutableSetMultimap has a builder:

```
ImmutableSetMulitimap.Builder<Key, Value> builder = ImmutableSetMulitimap.builder();
for (Entry<Key, Value> entry : entries) {
    builder.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
ImmutableSetMulitimap<Key, Value> map = builder.build();
```

For more info please see the [javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetMultimap.html)

Comment: My values of the map are not Key but Set<Key>

Comment: ImmutableSetMultimap puts values into Sets. If you put multiple values with the same key, meaning `builder.put(key, value)`, then all the values will be in a set. If you do `map.get(key)` you'll get a set of values. Please follow the link to javadoc and search for `get(K key)`

Comment: You're right, sorry it's a typo. Will fix it in a sec.